# Check which part of a list is consecutive (not using sort)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to understand how consecutive numbers could be found in a list. This is the code I’ve written so far:

```
v = []
while True:
    n = int(input("Insert a number (0 for exit) -> "))
    if n == 0: break
    v.append(n)

for i in range(len(v)):
    if v[i] - 1 == v[i - 1]:
        print(v[i - 1])
```

but this code doesn't print the last number of v[i], can someone help me?

Comment: What's the logic behind this condition `if v[i] - 1 == v[i - 1]` ?

Comment: if v[i] - 1 (then    if [4, 3, 2, 1],  v[4] - 1 == v[3]    ) then is consecutive (i don't know if it's the best way to do this)

Comment: your `for` loop should start at 1, because you do `v[i-1]` which is invalid for i = 0

Comment: can you add some sample input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I get your question right but a simple solution could be:

```
first = True
for i in range(1, len(v)):
    if v[i]-1 == v[i-1]:
        if first:
            first = False
            print("-")
            print(v[i-1])
        print(v[i])
    else:
        first = True
```

So that for an input like:

```
[4, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 8, 7]
```

you get:

```
-
1
2
3
4
-
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
for i in range(1, len(v)):
    if (v[i] - 1) == v[i - 1]:
        print(v[i])
```

Comment: In this case, it won't print first number

Comment: but first number  can't be consecutive

Comment: I also modified the code cause it would have give you an error